# Network manager keeps asking for login information with a Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 wireless card

Tags: wireless, network-manager, intel-wireless

I am having problems with wireless connections when I start my computer back up from standby after a while of it being in standby, and sometimes regular power up from full off as well though less often. The problem is that when connecting to the networks it will not connect and keep asking me for my login information over and over again.

One sort of fix that I found, but it doesn't work all the time, is to switch to a different network that I don't have on my network list already try to connect to that wait for it to fail then switch back to the network I really wanted and it seems to get the connection, however again this only sometimes works.

So I'm wondering if this is a known problem or if its just me. LSPCI below:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port (rev 02)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 06)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 06)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation GT218 [NVS 3100M] (rev a2)
01:00.1 Audio device: nVidia Corporation High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 (rev 35)
0d:00.0 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd MMC/SD Host Controller (rev 01)
0d:00.1 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd Memory Stick Host Controller (rev 01)
0d:00.3 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd FireWire Host Controller (rev 01)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
```

On Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: sounds like something is screwed up with the mechanism that stores your password. Are you using Network Manager? What version of Ubuntu (or variant)?

Comment: I am using the built in network manager and ubuntu 11.10 install not an upgrade from previous versions

Answer (score 1):

```
gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlagn.conf
```

Add the line `options iwlagn bt_coex_active=0`.

Comment: hell yeah, that's the solution for N-1000 on ibm x121e

Answer (score 1):

I have the same WiFi adapter (Lenovo X1) and I used to have a similar problem, especially when connecting to 5GHz networks. Connecting to 2.4GHz networks is a lot more stable. The problems significantly reduced when I updated to 12.04 (alpha at the time) and I haven't seen it recur for a few weeks now.

Note that I did an upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 so it's not a fresh install.

I'm not sure that's the answer you expected but it seems that upgrading to 12.04 is the way to go. There are other reasons too :-)

Note for everybody who suggest to check the keyring or connection settings: in my experience the problem is intermittent and is not related to settings.

Comment: Well this makes me think its a lenovo thing because I have a lenovo T410

Comment: its perhaps the driver causing the issues.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is an issue with your keyring. (assuming it is asking for your computer login information again)

To change the password you want to launch 'Password and Keys' then change the password to the password login. This should only be an issue if you have changed your password since initial install.

[image: Password and Keys dialog]

If you are being prompted to enter the wireless password again you may want to try changing the settings for the wireless SSID and ensure that it says that the SSID is available to everyone.

[image]

Comment: It was asking for the wireless password and yes it is available to everyone and all of the settings are correct on the type of network

Comment: Still might be an issue with the keyring... I would try changing those settings to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

In wireless settings, Uncheck *`Connect automatically`*. That worked for me.

Comment: That doesn't do a damned thing to help, and it doesn't solve the obvious issue with the crappy drivers