# Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 not working with 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, intel-wireless

Here is the information I was able to gather, if you need more just ask :

```
uname -r
3.2.0-24-generic

lspci  
Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 (revision 35)

cat /etc/network/intefaces 
auto lo iface lo 
inet loopback

sudo ifup wlan0
Ignoring unknown interface wlan0=wlan0.
```

My laptop is a Sager (clevo B5100M)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same wireless adapter on the same version of kernel in a Lenovo X1 and it works flawlessly. Having said that, other users have had issue with that wireless adapter with other Lenovo models: [Network manager keeps asking for login information with a Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 wireless card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124770/network-manager-keeps-asking-for-login-information-with-a-centrino-ultimate-n-63)

Are you trying to connect over a 2.4GHz connection or a 5GHz one? I've had issues on 5GHz.

Comment: I can't even seem to powerup the adapter, I can't see any network. The network manager says device not ready